# Joining tables in Rails through relation table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, join, has-many-through

I have three classes; User, Feed, and Entries. Users have one or more Feeds and Feeds have one or more Entries:

```
class Feed < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :entries
  has_many :feeds_users
  has_many :users, :through => :feeds_users, :class_name => "User"
end

Class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :feeds_users
  has_many :feeds, :through => :feeds_users, :class_name => "Feed"
end

class Entry < ActiveRecord:Base
  belongs_to :feed
end
```

The User and Feed classes are related through a third table:

```
class FeedsUser < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :feed
end
```

Now, my problem is that I need to get a certain user's feeds and each feed's latest n entries. I'm fiddling with something like this:

```
u = User.first
Feed.joins(:entries, :users).where(:entries => { :created_at => (Time.now-2.days)..Time.now }, :users => u)
```

My problem here is that this generates some SQL that tries to query "users" on the table "feeds" - which doesn't exist.

How do I go about creating a correct query that can give me all feeds and their latest 10 entries for a given user?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take out `has_many :feeds_users`. `:feeds_users` shouldn't be a model.

You should keep the table, but some Rails magic goes on behind the scenes. If you have a table named feeds and a table named users, Rails derives the table name of the look-up unless you specify it differently.

For your example:

```
Class Feed < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :users
end

Class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :feeds
end
```

It will look for the relationship in the `users_feeds` table. If it looked like this:

```
Class Feed < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
end

Class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :feeds
end
```

It would look for the relationship in the `user_feeds` table.

It's linguistically correct, as many users will have many feeds in the first example, and one user will have many feeds in the second example. That's also a good indicator of whether your relation logic is correct.

It also sounds like you need the `has_and_belongs_to_many` relationship instead of just `has_many`.

For a complete run-down on all forms of model associations, check out [the guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html).

Comment: Are you suggesting that I remove just the model or the table in the database as well? How do I maintain a many-to-many relation then?

Comment: Thanks, has_and_belongs_to_many works OK (meaning I can call `feeds´ and `users´ respectively) but my joins/where command still raises the same error: it tries to query a "user" field on the "feed" table.

Comment: Every time I've used HABTM i've always regretted it and gone back and had to retrofit an association model and used `has_many :through`.

Comment: Yeah, I've done that a few times as well. The helper methods are really nice, but unless you understand the "magic" it gets fairly convoluted very quickly.

Comment: There, now it works. Note: u.feeds is an array and "entries" a method on the array, so it won't return the expected list of entries. In my case I gave up using one magic line to give me what I need and created a small method on the User class that collects all relevant entries from all the user's feeds and returns them as a list. Good Enough(TM).

Comment: Ah, gotcha. I'll remove that out then. Sorry, no way to test at the moment - at work.